# How select lircd.conf location using ssh in OSMC?

Tags: osmc, lirc

How can I select and enable custom lirc configuration file using ssh only?

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please note that Stackexchange is supposed to be a Q&A, not a collection of tutorials. Your question could be more specific, e.g. state what you already tried and what's the result of those tests. Have a look here: https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/rc-how-to-configure-lirc/1912 and let us know if this helped.